# Poll SCM step is working fine in certain pipeline jobs on the other hand not working in particular jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Recently we are shifted from Maven jobs to Pipeline jobs, where we have implemented shared library concept.

Here we have configured Poll SCM to look for any new commits in the branch, same configuration we have done in two different Pipeline jobs.

Note: Both Job1 and Job2 are having same steps, cloning same repository and pointed to same branch.

Here starngely we have noticed that Job1 perfectly recognise the new commit changes in the branch, but Job2 doesn't.

I have compared the config.xml of both jobs, looks similar.

But i have observed the difference in polling logs.

Poll SCM log:

Job1(where SCM is working) is first looking for changes in my shared library repo path, and then i can see it is looking for the changes in the repo/branch which that job is configured to clone.

Job2(where SCM is not working) is first looking for changes in my shared library repo path, and then it says not changes. That's all. It is not even reaching to the repo/branch path which that job is configured to clone.

So we are recreating all of the pipeline jobs by copying Job1.

I would like the understand how this polling working in background, and why it is working fine in Job1 and not working efficiently in Job2 even though the configurations are similar.

Anything am i missing here ?

I hope already someone should have faced this issue, kindly share your thoughts. It will be big help to us.